# opsworks: How to deploy a solr stack on opsworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to setup a solr instance on opsworks using a custom cookbook. I am very new to chef and so I really don't know what I am doing.

I've created a cookbook that includes this cookbook:
https://github.com/hipsnip-cookbooks/solr

And specified my Stack to use that custom cookbook. But I don't see in the logs that solr is installed or running.

A little guidance please?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/timoschmidt/opsworks_solrcloud

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand OpsWorks likes a structure where multiple cookbooks live inside a repo see the [AWS OpsWorks repo](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks).

If you want to use a third party cookbook repo you can add it as a sub-module see [my OpsWorks cookbooks](https://github.com/onema/opsworks-chef-cookbooks) for an example.

Once you have updated your Custom Cookbook you must run the **"update custom cookbook"** From the `Stack>Run Command` section.

Finally make sure you specify the recipe you want to run in the correct life cycle event (most likely **Setup**) under `Layer>Solr>Edit>Setup`. `solr::default` or simply `solr` as the only recipe in that cookbook is the default one.

In this case the best way to test the whole process is launching a new instance.

Take a look at the instance logs, these will have more information of what recipes where executed and which ones failed. Some times there are descriptive messages that may lead you to the reason why things are not working.

Best of luck!